# SQL Server Job access denied

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-job, sql-agent

I have a few jobs i created in SQL Server which were setup and have been running for months. For some reason now howrever, whenever i try and add or edit a 'step' within a job, it comes up with 'Access Denied' this includes signing in with an admin account. Even when i create a new job with anaccount im signed in as it says this same message? i have so far tried a restart of the SQL Server. any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run sql by **run as administrator ** and use user **sa**

Comment: thanks so much, who knew it would be so simple!